# fsockopen doesn't work correctly with with if/else

Tags: php, fsockopen, if-statement

I have this PHP code

```
    $fp = @fsockopen($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 80, $errno, $errstr, 1);

if ($fp) {
    $url = "/";

    fputs($fp, "GET $url HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");
    $resp = '';

    while(!feof($fp)) {
        $resp .= fgets($fp, 1024);
    }

    if (preg_match('/^http\/1\.\d+ 401/i', $resp)) {
        echo "Requires authentication";
    } else {
        echo "No auth required.";
    }
} else {
    echo "Failed to connect on port 80, reason: $errstr";
}
```

I have edited this lines

```
    } else {
    echo "Failed to connect on port 80, reason: $errstr";
}
```

I just have writen 2 lines to check if $errstr # Connection refused

to be like this

```
        } else {
    if ($errstr != 'Connection refused') {
        echo "Ok;
    }  
}
```

But code doesn't work correctly

Can you check what is the problem please ?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason you're trying to do an HTTP request with socket operations, instead of just doing `file_get_contents($url)`?

Comment: Remove the `@` error suppression while testing, and see if there are any errors. Additionally, makesure that `allow_url_fopen` is set to true in your `ini`.

Comment: Looks like you are missing the closing quote on Ok.  Change `echo "Ok;` to `echo "Ok";`

Comment: Thank you Marc B and prodigitalson. myproblem has been solved.